# Kivy animation - decreasing duration?

Tags: python, kivy

I have widget class in kivy, which I animate on screen. By the time I want to slowly decrease animation duration so widget will move faster. My code change the duration but it didn't affect on screen. Why?

> my widget class:

```
class Obstacle3(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.animation = Animation(x =-self.width, duration=2)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.faster, 2)
        self.anim = True
        self.animation.bind(on_complete=self.vanish)
        self.animation.start(self)
    def faster(self, *args):
        if self.animation._duration <= 0.4:
            self.animation._duration = self.animation._duration 
        else:
            self.animation._duration = self.animation._duration - 0.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the duration after the animation has started will have no effect. But you can set the `transition` property of the `Animation` before you start it. To make the animation go faster later in the animation, try using `in_circ`, `in_cubic`, `in_quart`, `in_quint`, or `in_expo`.

Another approach is to call `self.animation.stop()`, then start another `Animation` when you want to increase the animation speed.

Comment: But my game is like there are obstacles like in flappy bird and you need to avoid to, as longer as you survive the obstacles will move faster, how to do it